# Application where memory size should not crosses 512MB of Permspace

Tags: java, jvm

I want to develop an application where memory size should not crosses 512MB of memory space.How can I achieve that so that if memory size increases 512MB then exception has been raised to enduser to configure permgen space ?

Comment: Using `java -Xms<size>` is not enough?

Comment: Daniel, i am looking for some kind of popup to be displayed from my application which informs user to configure memory.

Comment: Note: if your user is using Java 8, there is no permgen anymore.

Comment: I agree, they have introduces concept of metaspace, but is there any way to handle this kind of situation ?

Comment: Please explain why you want to do this. Your question contradicts itself.

Comment: How can we define memory boundaries for my application ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the [Java Management Extensions (JMX)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/remote/custom.html). The linked article provides an example to set up an interactive client into this API. Specifically, the [`MemoryMXBean`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryMXBean.html) will provide access to the different JVM heaps. Here's a terse example of the bean's usage:

```
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.lang.management.MemoryPoolMXBean;
import java.lang.management.MemoryUsage;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class PermGenMonitorTask implements Runnable {
    private MemoryPoolMXBean permgenBean = null;

    public PermGenMonitorTask() {
        List<MemoryPoolMXBean> beans = ManagementFactory.getMemoryPoolMXBeans();
        for(MemoryPoolMXBean bean : beans) {
            if(bean.getName().toLowerCase().indexOf("perm gen") >= 0) {
                permgenBean = bean;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        MemoryUsage currentUsage = permgenBean.getUsage();
        int percentageUsed = (int)((currentUsage.getUsed() * 100)
            / currentUsage.getMax());
        System.out.println(new Date() + ": Permgen " +
            currentUsage.getUsed() +
            " of " + currentUsage.getMax() +
            " (" + percentageUsed + "%)");
    }
}
```

Comment: That means you're doing something wrong. Read the JMX official documentation and search the web for some examples. It's pretty straightforward once you get it working.